# Windows 10 tablet not fluently communicating with Bluetooth printer

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, print-drivers, zebra-printer

- Tablet: Asus running Windows 10
- Printer: Zebra iMZ320
- Mode: Bluetooth

I am successfully able to pair the printer with the tablet and get the bluetooth pin code to print initially on the printer.

After that, I am unable to move forward with actually printing to the printer. As shown below, I see "**Driver is unavailable**".

[image]

[I also see that this may be a known issue as per the Zebra forums](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO8986&actp=LIST).

Just wondering if anyone was able to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You've connected it (via BT pairing), so now you need to install [the driver](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/printers/mobile/imz320.html#downloadlistitem_9aa) (just like any other device).

From Zerba's KB [Windows 8 Bluetooth Configuration for Zebra Printers](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO8721) step #5:

> At this point your printer should be paired with the PC.  **The next step is to download and install the appropriate driver for the printer being used.**  You can find the most current driver your printer on [Zebra.com](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads.html/) under that printer's support page.

Comment: Hi there, I have the driver installed but the issue still persists.